# 70s science fiction book series with intelligent alien dinosaurs/dumb Earth dinosaurs

Tags: story-identification, books

The series featured human characters, a man & woman, helping an intelligent alien T-rex-like female dinosaur who may have had wings.  They were on the run from someone through space. This group was possibly a galactic patrol force of some sort that one of the humans had once been a member of. There was also an Earth T-rex of normal dinosaur intelligence.  I'm unsure how he was obtained but the alien T-rex still liked him, was a possibility of breeding with him as I recall.  The male T-rex was kept restrained to keep him from harming the rest on the spaceship.  This book was part of a series of books of which I only ever read the one, it being I think part 3 and would have been printed sometime before 1977.  It seems to me the cover depicted the normal T-rex collared and chained.  The winged (?) alien T-rex was there as well along with perhaps a jagged alien landscape and a spaceship. 
It was not Anne McCaffrey's Dinosaur planet series, Ray Bradbury's Dinosaur Tales, Harry Harrison's West of Eden or David Bischoff's Dragonstar series.

Comment: Hi there! That's some info already; could you please take a look at [these guidelines on story-ID](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if they trigger any more memories you could [edit] in? Any more recollection of the plot, the covers?

Comment: I'll toss out "Day of the Dragonstar".  First book of a three book series.  https://www.amazon.com/Day-Dragonstar-Thomas-F-Monteleone-ebook/dp/B008H78MIU.  Also, possibly the "West of Eden" series by Harry Harrison.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/West_of_Eden

Comment: Thanx PEW, that looks like it!  You have no idea how many years I've been trying to figure this out.  Now, to buy a copy!

Comment: Until you got talking about space, I was thinking Zelazny's Roadmarks. There was a female dragon and a cloned t-rex, and the dragon said something about liking her men being the strong silent type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Having found an image of the book, this fits your description so I will change my comment to an answer.
Although not a (long) series as far as I know, the T-Rex characters could be from The Second Experiment by J O Jeppson (Mrs Asimov). The book was published in 1974 and there was a sequel 'The Last Immortal'.

The intelligent T-Rex was an alien named Rya, guarded by a robot called Tec. The not so intelligent T-Rex was a possible mate for her, found on their travels.

[image]

Comment: I'm a simple person. I see a winged T-Rex on a spaceship, I upvote.